# Cannot subscript a value of type Array<Element> with index of type CountableRange<Int>

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

**Error:**
**Cannot subscript a value of type Array with index of type CountableRange**

I want to find say some top elements from any array/Sequence.

```
extension Array {
    func top(max:Int) -> Array {
        guard self.count > max else {
            return self
        }
        let last = max - 1
        return self[0..<max]
    }
}
```

Comment: This already exists, in the form of [`Array.prefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix)

Comment: Apart from the issue isn't it supposed to be `self[0..<last]`? The yellow warnings are sometimes as important as the red errors.

Comment: `max - 1` causes this to crash when `max` is `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality already exists in the standard library, in the form of [`Array.prefix(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix)

But to address the issue in this code:

The error here is actually not actually that you can't `subscript a value of type Array with index of type CountableRange`, but rather, that you can't do so to produce a result of type `Array`.

Subscripting an `Array` by a range yields an `ArraySlice`, not an `Array`. Thus, your code would have to be:

```
extension Array {
    func first(_ maxLength: Int) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        return self[0 ..< Swift.min(maxLength, self.count)]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the guard and returning self just using Swift min method in your upper bound. `return self[0..<Swift.min(maxLength, count)]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Oooooo, I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Leo and @Alexander for your prompt replies :)

```
extension Array {
    func first(max: Int) -> Array {
        return Array(prefix(max))
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to use guard just use `Array(prefix(max))` it will return an empty array if the array is empty

Comment: What if array.count < max  ??

Comment: It will return less elements